# Standard mesh for Concave Hexagons with two Mouths?

Tags: geometry, mesh, finite-element-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex

I am planning a visualization of flows though Concave Bisymmetric hexagons with two mouths.

Example where the length of the side d1 equals the other length of the side d2:

[image]

which naming I discussed initially [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1295168/17474) about Irregular hexagons.

There is the standard Mesh tool where you can draw your own meshes but I would like have some standard library such that I can cooperate better with others with the flow simulations later. 
I did not find any Mesh library for Hexagons in MathCentral File Exchange [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=hexagon).

Is there any standard Mesh library for irregular hexagon shapes?
I am open to any other languages too because I could read the code and convert it those standards to Matlab library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed this issue with my colleque. 
He motivates to create a triangle network but also points out general algorithms for nonconvex polygons.

## To create a Mesh by own algorithm

1. divide the hexagon into two trapezoids by the dashed line as illustrated in the body of the question
2. divide trapezoids into triangles: `assemmbly` and construct trimesh structures by `inittri`
3. load vector `f` is built by `bilin_assembly` (because this worked before but not necessarily the optimal choice)

Division of hexagon with two mouths into two trapezoids

1. take two nodes which index difference is three and which distance is smallest among six nodes.
2. form two trapezoids such that one trapezoid has numbers 1-4 while the other 1,6,5,4.

The following syntaxes are based on my editions of codes in 2013 but mostly on descriptions of the book *Numerical solutions of partial differential equations by the finite element method* by Claes Johnson.

Syntax of assembly where considered now for simplicity a Poisson problem (must be later refined here)

```
% [S,f]=assemblyGlobal(loadfunction,mesh)
%
%   loadfunction = function on the right-hand side of the Poisson equation
%   mesh         = mesh structure on which the assembly is done
%
%   S            = stiffness matrix of the Poisson problem
%   f            = load vector corresponding to loadfunction
```

where we need bilinear assembly which syntax

```
% function B=bilin_assembly(bilin,mesh)
%
%  bilin = function handle to integrand of the bilinear form
%          given as bilin(u,v,ux,uy,vx,vy,x,y), where
%          u  - values of function u
%          v  - values of function v
%          ux - x-derivative of function u
%          uy - y-derivative of function u
%          vx - x-derivative of function v
%          vy - y-derivative of function v
%          x  - global x-coordinate
%          y  - global y-coordinate
%  mesh  = mesh structure on which the matrix will be assembled
%
%  B     = matrix related to bilinear form bilin
```

Syntax to init triangular mesh

```
% function mesh = inittri(p,t)
%
%   p       = nodes
%   t       = triangles
%     
%   mesh    = trimesh structure corresponding to (p,t)
%
% TRIMESH STRUCTURE :
% 
%   p       = nodes in a 2xN-matrix
%
%   t       = triangles in a 3xN- matrix (nodes of the triangles as indeces to the p- matrix).
% 
%   edges   = a matrix of all edges in the mesh. Each column is an edge :
%             [n1 ; n2] where n1 < n2;
%
%   t2e     = a matrix connecting  triangle's and edges's. 
%             Each column corresponds to a triangle and has
%             triangle's edges in the order n1->n2, n2->n3,
%             n1->n3. 
%
%   e2t     = inverse of t2e.
```

I did no post the complete source codes here because of copyright issues and they would make the answer rather long. 
However, all algorithms are based on the first source so can be created by any researcher here.
I think this kind of FEM method is the only way to find the optimum mesh here.

### Algorithms for general nonconvex polygons

There are also algorithms which can create meshes for general nonconvex polygons. 
It is possible that the mesh provided by Margus' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31049317/54964) is produced by such an algorithm.

### Ansys

I was experiencing different products about visualizing holes, different geometries and different materials. 
[Ansys](http://www.ansys.com/) is promising solution here.

### Sources

1. *Numerical solutions of partial differential equations by the finite element method* by Claes Johnson.
2. Class notes in Finite Element Methods at my university, 2013-2014

Comment: I had to accept this one here because it is the only answer that offers a systematic way to find the standard mesh. I am more than happy to answer any better answer which can provide free source codes for systematic testing.

Answer (score 3):

For example you could take a look of example done by Alexandra Baumgart and Hazuki Okuda using Mathematica. This is implemented with **[Manipulate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)** effectively creating a basic UI.

[image]

Code:

```
Manipulate[
Grid[{{Show[
ParametricPlot3D[{1.25Cos[t], 1.25 Sin[t],s+2-2w},{s,0,.25},{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Gray],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"], 
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t],2.25-2w},{r,0,1.25},{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Gray],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t],2-2w},{r,0,1.25},{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Gray],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],
ParametricPlot3D[{1.25Cos[t], 1.25 Sin[t],s-2.25+2w},{s,0,.25},{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Gray],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t],-2.25+2w},{r,0,1.25},{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Gray],Mesh->None],
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t],-2+2w},{r,0,1.25},{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Gray],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],  
ParametricPlot3D[{(1-s/2) Cos[t],(1-s/2) Sin[t],Max[0,-s+2 ]},{s,Min[2-(2^(2/3) (2 \[Pi]-Min[2Pi,3 V((w^2)/(.04))])^(1/3))/\[Pi]^(1/3)-w,1.99],2},{t,0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Hue[a]],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t],Max[0,(2^(2/3) (2 \[Pi]-Min[2Pi,3 V((w^2)/(.04))])^(1/3))/\[Pi]^(1/3)-w]},{r,0, .000000000001+w+((2^(2/3) (2 \[Pi]-Min[2Pi,3 V((w^2)/(.04))])^(1/3))/\[Pi]^(1/3)-w)/2},{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1], Hue[a]],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], Min[0,-(2^(2/3) (2 \[Pi]-Min[2Pi,3 V((w^2)/(.04))])^(1/3))/\[Pi]^(1/3)]},{r, 0, .00000000001+w+((2^(2/3) (2 \[Pi]-Min[2Pi,3 V((w^2)/(.04))])^(1/3))/\[Pi]^(1/3)-w)/2},{t,0,2Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Hue[a]],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],
ParametricPlot3D[{(1-s/2) Cos[t],(1-s/2) Sin[t],Min[0,s -2 ]},{s,w,2},{t,0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[.2],Gray],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],ParametricPlot3D[{(1-s/2) Cos[t],(1-s/2) Sin[t],Max[0,-s + 2 - w]},{s,w,2},{t,0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[.2],Gray],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"], 
ParametricPlot3D[{(1-s/2) Cos[t],(1-s/2) Sin[t],Min[0,s-2+ w]},{s,w,Min[2-(2^(2/3) (2 \[Pi]-Min[2Pi,3 V((w^2)/(.04))])^(1/3))/\[Pi]^(1/3)-w,2]},{t,0, 2 Pi},Mesh->None, PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1],Hue[a]], Lighting->"Neutral"],  ParametricPlot3D[{(w/2) Cos[t],(w/2) Sin[t], b},{t,0,2Pi}, {b, -2 + w, 0}, PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[1], Hue[a]],Mesh->None, Lighting->"Neutral"],PlotRange->All,ImageSize->{300,300}, SphericalRegion-> True]},{Row[{Text["time to empty = "], Text[2Pi (.04)/(3w^2)],Text[" seconds"]}]}}],{start,ControlType->None},{end,ControlType->None},
{{V,.01,"time (seconds)"},0.01,34,.01,ControlType->Animator,AnimationRate->1,AnimationRunning->False,ImageSize->Small}, 
{{w,.05,"neck width (millimeters)"}, .05, .3,.01,Appearance->"Labeled"}, 
{{a,0,"color of sand"}, 0, 1,Appearance->"Labeled"}]
```

Source: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FlowTimeInAnHourglass/

Comment: Nice! Even simpler mesh would be nice where no morphology of hourglass. Just simple concave hexagon with double mouths is required. Some simple so it can be used as a standard later on. Comparison has to be done to explain why the chosen-one will be the better one than any else. It would be nice if you could simplify the proposal.

Comment: "Comparison has to be done to explain why the chosen-one will be the better one than any else.", well you should then have an idea of what is better (normally you do not know this). In real life, i know this problem is solved slightly differently. I think it was called "iterative learning", basically you randomize parameters and test how well they perform. After that you repeat, but favor collection of parameters what have performed well so far. You might also be able to train neural network with feedback to do this for you.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is the reason why this thread is here to get some standard. To get ideas and reasons why something is better than another. Any method to explain is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If this is to stand-in as purely the presentation layer, then it really depends on the output of the simulation and the representation you select for it.

For example, if the simulation outputs one single variable (e.g. the volume of one of the compartments), then this could be assigned directly to an attribute of the visualisation such as the location of the "top" cap of a cylinder. A "complementary" cylinder could stand on top of the previous one with its bottom-cap coordinates assigned to (totalVolume-lowerCompartmentVolume).

In this case, the visualisation is just a dashboard and does not feed back into the simulation (e.g. object collisions or proximity in general are not taken into account by the simulation).

To generalise this, we are talking about a solution where a set of quantities is assigned to a set of visualisation attributes.

From this point of view, a set of complex objects could be created using VRML (or X3D), their attributes could be binded directly to simulation outputs and the rendering be triggered every n-th simulation timestep.

To create the "scene" or visualisation objects, you can use a software like [blender](https://www.blender.org/) which can export VRML scenes, or write the [VRML](http://gun.teipir.gr/VRML-amgem/spec/index.html) manually (it is really a straightforward task).

In terms of infrastructure, MATLAB has a [VRML toolkit](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/sl3d/vrml.html) and Python has a really wide selection of modules by which VRML can be handled (please see [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVRML97) and [this](http://code.astraw.com/projects/pyosg/) link for example).

For a more concrete example:

Given some simulation output `y` and a template VRML file like:

```
#VRML V2.0 utf8
Transform {
  translation 0 0 0
  children [
    Shape { geometry Box {2,2,zSize} }
  ]
}
```

You could do something like:

```
data = (Read contents of VRML file as string data).
for n in [0..1000]:
    y = getSimulationOutput(aParameterVector)
    renderData = substitute(data, "zSize", y) #This function could be provided by a template module like jinja for example. 
    simulationFrame = renderVRML(renderData)
    saveImage(simulationFrame)
```

(Please note: More information about Jinja can be found [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) - comment inline link not rendering properly above.)

Going back into the file and binding different elements to different quantities (for example, changing the transform which can rotate, scale, translate the box, or changing the appearance of the box by assigning a different colour), you can create any sort of "dashboard" output for your simulation....including irregular hexagons.

This technique is a direct application of [Data Driven Documents](http://d3js.org/) but to a different substrate (than HTML or SVG) here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer! Is there a link missing in the second last sentence in the word `here`?

Comment: Thank you, no, the "here" does not imply a link in this case, it is meant to say that this is essentially a D3 technique but in this case applied over a different substrate than the usual HTML / SVG one.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to visualize such hexagons in matlab, then [`fill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) and [`fill3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html) should do the trick. Here is an example code, which assumes that your hexagons are parameterized by two widths `w1` and `w2` and the `d1` and `d2` parameters which are lengths of the sides:

```
function draw_hexagon(w1, w2, d1, d2)
    a=(w1-w2)/2;
    b1=sqrt(d1^2 - a^2);
    b2=sqrt(d2^2 - a^2);

    xs=[-w1/2, w1/2, w2/2, w1/2, -w1/2, -w2/2];
    ys=[b1, b1, 0, -b2, -b2, 0];

    fill(xs, ys, 'b')
    axis square 
    grid on
end
```

It will produce the following for `w1=4, w2=2, d1=2, d2=3`:

[image]

And similarly for 3D:

```
function draw_hexagon_3d(w1, w2, d1, d2)
    a=(w1-w2)/2;
    b1=sqrt(d1^2 - a^2);
    b2=sqrt(d2^2 - a^2);

    xs=[-w1/2, w1/2, w2/2, w1/2, -w1/2, -w2/2];
    ys=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    zs=[b1, b1, 0, -b2, -b2, 0];

    fill3(xs, ys, zs, 'b')
    grid on
    axis square 
end
```

we get:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer again! So simple but elegant. Exactly what we need here. I think your solution have even less parameters than Bert's because you do not have angle directly but it can deduced secondarily from your parameters.

Comment: I didn't initially notice that d1 and d2 are lengths of the sides. I fixed that now in the code above so the parameterization is based on the widths and lengths of sides.

Comment: Nice implementation! This assumes the top and bottom sides are parallel and the hexagonal has has vertical ax of symmetry.

Comment: Assuming you don't need the other degrees of freedom, you can rearrange these ones as follows. By replacing w1 and d1 by their ratio r1 (and equally r2), and adding rw as w1/r2, you fully define the shape and can set the size in an independent parameter.

Comment: I added below a Wiki page about how to construct finally the Mesh through syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to set a standard mesh library, I believe we should start by determining the degrees of freedom.

For concave bissymetric hexagons with 2 mouths it could be:

1. mouth ax width (W_m)
2. relative top width (w_t = W_t / W_m)
3. relative bottom width (w_b = W_b / W_m)
4. relative top height
5. relative bottom height

The answers from Margus and A_A will be helpful for the realization.

Comment: Actually, I think your answer better answers the question than Margus and A_A. The point is to understand what to standardize for a standard mesh. Excellent ideas!